# python requests, I got different response status than postman's result.

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

requests: 2.19.1

python: 3.6

url(It's just url, There's no special meaning): http://moneycake.tistory.com/43

Python code(actually, pycharm django code):

```
try:
    r = requests.head('http://moneycake.tistory.com/43', allow_redirects=False)
    print(r.status_code)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    pass
```

It returns `>>> 403`

But when I do this on [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) with method `GET` and default settings,

It returns `200 OK`.

Why this happen?

And How can I get `200 OK` status response on pycharm?

Comment: Perhaps different request headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the User-Agent:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}

try:
    r = requests.head('http://moneycake.tistory.com/43', allow_redirects=False, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    pass
```

**Output**

```
200
```